# Rendering static images with img tag using v-html not working

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to render a html string into a `div` using `v-html` but it's not able to resolve the image path.
The image is stored as follows `/src/assets/logo.png` .

My project has already setup the copy-webpack-plugin.

The html string is as follows:

```
<img src="../assets/logo.png" /><br/><p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Did you tried using `/assets/logo.png` or `./assets/logo.png`

Comment: @hamzox yeap, tried both

Comment: Put your `logo.png` to `static` folder and change `src` attribute to `"/logo.png"`